# Finding probabilities given continous random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, random-variables

Given the random variable $Y_1 \sim \mathcal{N}(μ, σ^2 )$

Where $μ=350$ and $σ^2 =12365$

How can one calculate probability that the random variable $Y_1$ is max 275

Likewise how would you find the probability that the random variable $Y_1$ is at least 425 ?

Im not sure how one would solve this problem using the Φ function

Comment: How do you calculate probabilities? How would you write out your first question in a mathematical way? Are you suppose to standardized the normal variable and consult a table?

Comment: not quite sure what you mean

Comment: @EmilB the point is, what do you already know how to do? Then we can help you get past where you are stuck

Comment: Im trying to figure out how to use the CDF(Φ) to find the probabilities given, look at tommiks answer below. However im not sure on how to do it for 425

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$P(Y_1\leq 275)=\Phi\left(\frac{275-350}{\sqrt{12365}}\right)\approx 0.25$$

and similarly the second question.

Comment: is there a difference between max and least, in this context? Or is it the same formula for both?

Comment: @EmilB: similar formula $P(Y_1>425)=1-P(Y_1\leq 425)$

Comment: @Emilio calculate it with the same formula and then take the complement to 1

Comment: Nevermind, i get it. Its because wolfram alpha doesnt understand when you $1-(formula)$, so you have to use the actual result of the formula and then -1.

However what is the explanation as to why you would have to minus 1 when its "at least" a value and not do it when its "max" a value

Comment: @Emilio: this means to do $1-0.7499\approx0.25$

Comment: Shouldnt $(_1>425)$ be $(_1≥425)$ when $Y_1$ is at least 425?

Comment: @Emilio: $P(Y_1=425)=0$

Comment: I see but why do we minus one?

Comment: @Emilio because $P(Y_1<k)+P(Y_1>k)=1$